# Jenkins api too slow

Tags: java, rest, jenkins

Im using Jenkins on my local in docker from jenkins official docker hub (but I even tried jenkins we have on bluemix instance).

Im writing program (test driven currently) to trigger job from java and then get job id, using
jenkins api.

```
Properties jenkinsProps = new Properties();
InputStream jenkinsPropsIs = Files.newInputStream(jenkinsPropsFilePath);
jenkinsProps.load(jenkinsPropsIs);

// for building url
String jenkinsServerUrl = jenkinsProps.getProperty(JenkinsPropertiesKeys.KEY_JENKINS_SERVER_URL);
String jobName = jenkinsProps.getProperty(JenkinsPropertiesKeys.KEY_JENKINS_JOB_NAME);
String jobRemoteAccessToken = jenkinsProps.getProperty(JenkinsPropertiesKeys.KEY_JENKINS_JOB_ACCESS_TOKEN);

// for headers
String jenkinsUser = jenkinsProps.getProperty(JenkinsPropertiesKeys.KEY_JENKINS_USERNAME);
String jenkinsUserApiToken = jenkinsProps.getProperty(JenkinsPropertiesKeys.KEY_JENKINS_API_TOKEN);
String jenkinsCrumb = jenkinsProps.getProperty(JenkinsPropertiesKeys.KEY_JENKINS_CSRF_CRUMB);

// build parameters
Map<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
params.put("param1", "test1");
params.put("param2", "test2");
params.put("param3", "test3");

// Jenkins cause - to identify which process had run this job
String procID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
params.put("cause", procID);

String url = getJenkinsBuildWithParametersUrl(jenkinsServerUrl, jobName, jobRemoteAccessToken, params);

WebRequest request = new WebRequest(); // own HttpConnection based client
// setup Jenkins crumb to avoid CSRF
request.setHeader(HEADER_NAME_JENKINS_CRUMB, jenkinsCrumb);

// user authentification (Basic + base64 encoded user:apiToken)
setupAuthenticationHeader(request, jenkinsUser, jenkinsUserApiToken);

// execute POST request
request = request.post(url);

// asserts
assertNotNull(request);
assertEquals(201, request.getResponseCode());


/* GET JOB ID */
Thread.currentThread().sleep(8000); // !!! if less then 8sec, jenkins returns old job number

request.reset();
setupAuthenticationHeader(request, jenkinsUser, jenkinsUserApiToken);
url = getJenkinsLastBuildUrl(jenkinsServerUrl, jobName);

// execute get request to /api/json
request = request.get(url);
assertTrue(request.isOK());

// get note & compare with proc id, to match job
String jenkinsJobProcId = null;
JsonObject jenkinsLastBuildJson = request.getResponseAsJson();
JsonArray jenkinsActions = jenkinsLastBuildJson.get("actions").getAsJsonArray();
for (JsonElement action : jenkinsActions) {
    JsonObject actionJson = action.getAsJsonObject();
    if (actionJson.get("_class").getAsString().equals("hudson.model.CauseAction")) {
        JsonArray causeActionJsonArray = actionJson.get("causes").getAsJsonArray();
        for (JsonElement cause : causeActionJsonArray) {
            JsonObject causeJson = cause.getAsJsonObject();
            if (causeJson.get("_class").getAsString().equals("hudson.model.Cause$RemoteCause")) {
                jenkinsJobProcId = causeJson.get("note").getAsString();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!jenkinsJobProcId.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("LastBuild prodId      : " + jenkinsJobProcId);
assertEquals(procID, jenkinsJobProcId);

// get jenkins build number
int lastBuildNumber = jenkinsLastBuildJson.get("number").getAsInt();
System.out.println("LastBuild buildNumber : " + lastBuildNumber);
assertTrue(lastBuildNumber > 0);
```

Once i trigger job, it takes like 8 sec, to job apear in /api/json.

Do you know what can be the problem ?

How to tune it up ?

Comment: You should provide some more details. 1) What code are you using? - provide a snippet. 2) What have you already tried to narrow the problem? - I did A and got B. 3) What are your hardware specs? - CPU, RAM, disk. .... Something like that.

Comment: I am using standard jenkins apis, calling with java httpconnection. I am running jenkins on docker on my macbook pro. nothing special to describe.

Comment: How do you measure the time between successful job trigger and the visibility in the api? Anything helpful in the Jenkins log?

Comment: I am sleeping execution of getting last build id with `Thread.currentThread().sleep(8000);` so in cas 8sec wait, its fine. If less then 8sec, in json response there is old jobId. I am calling `{JENKINS}/job/{JOB_NAME}/lastBuild/api/json` to get job number. I even tried with browser refreshing api, and it really takes some time to current job number apears in response json - even job is already running in jenkins queue

Comment: added code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you still need a delay between the two executions.

**trigger the job**

```
curl -X POST http://${JENKINS_HOTS}:${JENKINS_PORT}/job/${JOB_NAME}/build \
  --user ${USER}:${PASSWORD} \
  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"delay", "value":"0sec"}]}'
```

**get job info**

```
curl http://${JENKINS_HOTS}:${JENKINS_PORT}/job/${JOB_NAME}/api/json \
  --user ${USER}:${PASSWORD}
```

If you still need to wait around 8 seconds, check the setting of the `quiet period` in the job. If it's not yet enabled, enable it and set the period to `0 seconds`. This should remove the delay between the executions.

Depending on the workload off the Jenkins instance it might be necessary, even with a period of zero seconds, that you need to wait a short period.